# How to make a X-Y plot

Tags: r, plot

I am not sure how to make a X-Y plot by R.
I have A B C datasets.

```
 A dataset
 ID    Result  
 1.1      2  
 1.2      4  
 1.3      2.5  
 1.4      9  
 B dataset   
 ID    Result    
 1.1      1   
 1.2      7   
 1.3      6   
 1.4      9     
 C dataset  
 ID    Result  
 1.1      0.5  
 1.2      8   
 1.3      9   
 1.4      9
```

I want to make a plot X=result A , y=the result B, the other plot x=result A and Y=result C....

then A represented by red spots, B is black and C is blue for example. So the spot 1.1 should be x=2 and y=1 in red (A) and block (B). the spot 4,7, it means it is ID 1.2 in red and block....  The spot 9,9 it means is is ID 1.4 in the red and block.....

I try qqplots but I dont know how to make the X and Y correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot2 is an excellent library for producing plots and there are many reference manuals online.  Below is an answer to your question using the ggplot approach.  The A,B,C data frames are unified into a single frame and the geom_point() for an x-y plot is used.  The aes() sets the x and y coordinates (here you seem to seek to plot 'result' as both the x and y, if I understood the question?).  The points are scaled by color, which is defined in the data frame as attributes A,B,C.  Importantly, this variable must be a factor.  The colors are defined by the manual color scale.

```
library(ggplot2)
dataA <- data.frame(ID=c(1.1,1.2,1.3),result=c(2,4,2.5),index=c(1,2,3),color="A")
dataB <- data.frame(ID=c(1.1,1.2,1.3),result=c(1,7,6),index=c(1,2,3),color="B")
dataC <- data.frame(ID=c(1.1,1.2,1.3),result=c(0.5,8,9),index=c(1,2,3),color="C")

data <- rbind(dataA,dataB,dataC)
data$color <- as.factor(data$color)
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x=result,y=result,color=color,size=10)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "black", "blue")) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I think that I make a mistake. I want to make a X-Y plot that X=result A Y=result B. So the ID 1.1 represented in the dataset set A is 2 and dataset B is 1. Thank you.

Comment: The above answer will plot what you need, it's a matter of how your data frame is arranged.  From your comment, it's now unclear what "dataC" is about ... but instead of setting color=color then set color=ID and it will color by your ID values instead as follows: library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(ID=c(1.1,1.2,1.3), resultA=c(2,4,2.5), resultB=c(1,7,6))
data$ID <- as.factor(data$ID)
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x=resultA,y=resultB,color=ID,size=10)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "black", "blue")) +
  theme_bw()